# How to rotate image when scrolling using CSS transform?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not sure how to use using jQuery, but has a CSS3 property: transform: rotate

it could be used along with jQuery?

```
transform:rotate;
-ms-transform:rotate;
-webkit-transform:rotate;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g3k6h/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You have to show an attempt, you can't say please do it for me

Comment: rotate the image while scroll on body

Comment: You mean you want the gear to rotate when the page is scrolled up and down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kDSqB/

It's not 100% accurate in working out full rotation, but I think that night be the fiddle environment.

The code here:

```
var $cog = $('#cog'),
$body = $(document.body),
bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $cog.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I was going to use this kind of solution, but instead posted one where the rotation doesn't depend on the scroll position, it just spins while you are scrolling.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple jQuery example, check the modified JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g3k6h/5/

CSS will handle rotations > 360 and < 0 for me so I didn't even bother doing that and adjust the rotation value based on the distance scrolled. I didn't worry about trying to account for a full rotation either so that it better flowed with the speed and distance scrolled. This solution depends on jQuery but could easily be done without it.

```
$(function() {
  var rotation = 0, 
    scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
    rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
    var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
    $(".gear").css({
      "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
      "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
      "transform": rotationStr
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Not "Nicer" per se, but different. To each their own. It all depends on the needs of application and I don't think either of ours fit those needs.

Comment: I was looking to achieve something like this: https://superglow.co/ - so looks like your solution will work well for it!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same result, in a more simple way using DOM javascript, instead of jQuery. Give your image an id, and add the following javascript:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {scrollRotate()};<br/>
<br/>
function scrollRotate() {<br/>
  var navimg = document.getElementById("navimg");<br/>
  navimg.style.transform = "rotate("+ (window.pageYOffset/5) + "deg)"<br/>
}
</script>
```

Where it says "window.pageYOffset/5", you can lower the number (5) for a faster rotation, or make it higher for a slower rotation.

Comment: Works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

I started with OneOfOne's solution and added animations to it. Start the animation on the `scroll` event, end it with the `mouseup`. http://jsfiddle.net/g3k6h/4/

```
var rotation = 0;
var interval;
var gear = $('.gear');

function animate() {
    gear.css('transform', 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)');
    rotation += 10;
    rotation %= 360;
}
function startAnim() {
    if (!interval) {
        interval = setInterval(animate, 100);
    }         
}    
function stopAnim() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
}    
$(document).scroll(startAnim).mouseup(stopAnim);
```

jamesgauld's answer is similar to mine except that the rotation amount is based on the scroll position, where mine just keeps rotating while you are scrolling, which is how I understood the question.

Comment: I think after reading OP's comment below I think this is likely the correct solution.

Comment: @jamesgauld please don't use below referring to a different answer, order of answers can changes. Yo do mean the OP's comment under OneOfOne's answer, right?

Comment: sorry, yes this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540474/how-to-rotate-image-when-scrolling-using-css-transform/18540693?noredirect=1#comment27270528_18540538

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, jQuery should use the correct css3 prefix.
http://jsfiddle.net/g3k6h/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('.gear').click(function() {
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(30deg)'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the tricky part, which is syncing the rotation with the div's scrolling.

Comment: css should be faster since on recent builds of webkit it's hardware accelerated.

Comment: not click scroll it, and the image would have to run infinitely. thanks.

Comment: @Leo No you can't, look at the doc for animate, transform is not supported

Comment: @OneOfOne CSS isn't necessarily hardware accelerated, at least not on all devices. The 3D transforms are hardware accelerated but not 2D. I got into this trying to shift a div left/right and it was much smoother after moving to a `translate3D`