# Rotation of a image and making the text to come later over the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make the image rotate while the website is being scrolled, and make text appear on top of the image later?
How do I make  changes in the style to be carried out automatically, like the rotation of an image, or text falling on the image while scrolling?

Comment: there are so many jquery plugin here , if you want the animation just google it , and if you get any error post the question here

Comment: For scrolling actions I recommend [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). For anmiations you can use jQuery and CSS transitions.

Comment: Thank you all for your  reply..

Comment: Can you send me the plugin or the library to be used in a website to make the styles dynamic like text comes later after the image comes first in a slider..

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#fixedImage').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($(document.body).scrollTop() / $(document.body).height() * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

```css
body {
   
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0;
}

#fixedImage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index:-1;
  background:red;
}
#fixedImage img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.text{
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<body>
    <div id="fixedImage">
      
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg">
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="text">
    
         <p>
         
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
         </p>
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can make it with jquery like this.or you can find a lot of plugins for this effect

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#fixedImage').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($(document.body).scrollTop() / $(document.body).height() * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

On  window.scroll function write the tanimations that you want to perform 
check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/18540697/7011496