# Make an image rotate on page scroll

Tags: html, css, animation, image-rotation

I'm trying to connect the rotation of an object to the scroll.
Here's how cargo tells you to rotate an image: start by opening Code View while editing a page; then wrap the element you want to rotate with a div that has the class ‘rotate’.

```
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

and then add this to the CSS:

```
.rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to connect this rotation to the page scrolling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate image when scrolling using CSS transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540474/how-to-rotate-image-when-scrolling-using-css-transform)

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you want? It the element at a fixed position in the viewport? Does the amount/speed it is to rotate/rotate at related at all to the amount/speed of scrolling etc? You have not tagged JavaScript but it is likely to be needed for this task.

Comment: The element is fixed, the amount of rotation is related to the amount of speed. I'm using cargo collective so I can use JavaScript